# country_code list for geocoder gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-geocoder

I'm using [geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) to detect country user.

On my app I need detect country user. I make something like:

```
c = request.location.country_code
  case c
    when 'US'
     I18n.locale = :en
    when 'ES'
     I18n.locale = :es
    else
     locale ||= I18n.default_locale
   end
```

**My question is where can I find a `country_code` list for my other languages?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the documentation for the provider you're using. For example, Google returns ISO 3166-1 codes.

http://www.iso.org/iso/iso-3166-1_decoding_table.html

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

The table listed above is no longer available.

Please see this one for reference.

http://labs.apnic.net/dists/regiontablecc.html